# How to make a compact redstone circuit that triggers an output every 4 redstone inputs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm trying to make an automatic beetroot farm. I'm using observers behind the plants and dispensers with water.  Each plant has 4 observer stages.  The observer is triggered when:

1. the seeds are planted.
2. the seeds grow one stage.
3. the beetroots grow another stage.
4. the beetroots are ready to harvest.

The obvious solution is to make a kind of counter that waits until the observer has been triggered 4 times and then triggers the dispensers.  I am not sure how to achieve this, although I imagine it will involve some sort of hopper with 4 items.

How do I achieve this while still keeping it compact enough to fit in a beetroot row?

(I am doing one dispenser per row, and I will plant the beetroot that triggers the observer last so that all the beetroot will be harvest ready when the dispensers are triggered)

Comment: You'll need some sort of counter which keeps track of the number of growths so far.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  The first thing that comes to mind is some sort of hopper clock, but that would be expensive to do for every observer.

Comment: You could do one giant hopper clock so that the entire farm gets harvested once all the crops are fully grown. Some crops will be get left at the grown state for a little while so not the most time-efficient whilst actually running but it is resource-efficient,.

Comment: That's a good idea but I'd prefer the counter.  I'm going to edit my question to make it a more specific about how to create a counter like that.

Comment: The edit changed the question quite a lot, would it have been better to create a new question, or was editing the best option?

Comment: @Millard No, if it's the same fundamental problem but you believe asking it differently will get you a better answer, editing is the right choice.

Comment: This should be a new question as it is asking how to do something else. The original question could have more answers than the one I gave but you have now limited the scope away from the original question.

Comment: @Halesy , that's true, but that's the way I want to do it, and I need to know how to do this so I can apply it to more redstone circuits as well.  I have just made it more specific.

Comment: Just for reference in case anyone wants to know, you can make a fairly efficient beetroot farm simply with two villagers and no redstone

Answer (score 2):

After spending some time in my redstone testing world, this is what I came up with. I am by far not the best redstoner so someone will probably be able to make this more compact. I decided to chain 2 t-flip flops together to get to your desired result. See the image for how to build it.[image]

Both hoppers need to start with 1 item in them, the 6 droppers should remain empty. The piston is a sticky piston. The input is the observer at the bottom left, every 4 updates the dropper at the top left will drop 1 item (change this to your needs)